# How to take screen shot of sharepoint site programmically

Tags: ribbon

Currently i have created a custom button in my sharepoint ribbon bar and i need a code for taking screen shot of the page when the custom button is clicked. since there is login credential i cannot able to take screen shot.

Regards,

Zakeer Ahamed.S

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, not 100% sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but there is a third party product that allows you to create a PDF of a SharePoint page from [the UI](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html), [SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/converting-sharepoint-lists-to-pdf.html), [Nintex Workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/08/convert-html-to-pdf-using-nintex.html) or [web service call](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html).

Please note that I worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.

Comment: Thanks i am trying to do same as a product of Muhimbi in which trying to convert the webpage to pdf .